# Android, trying to figure out how animate a bitmap, have timer working, but don't know how to update screen

Tags: android

I got some sample code from her to update text control of a timer.  Next I created a custom View and override the onDraw so I could have animation for the View.  The custom view has a bitmap that for now just move it down one pixel every time the timer goes off then get more fancy after that is working.

I was thinking about calling my custom views invalidate from the timer call, so my OnDraw function will be called.  But then I would not know if its coming from the timer, meaning I will have to move the bitmap, or just from android updating the screen.

What is the best way to do this???
Code with timer

```
package besttecksolutions.tellafortune;

/////////////
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Handler.Callback;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class cShuffle2  extends Activity   {
    TextView text3;
    long starttime = 0;
    //this  posts a message to the main thread from our timertask
    //and updates the textfield

   //runs without timer be reposting self
   Handler h2 = new Handler();
   Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
           int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
           int minutes = seconds / 60;
           seconds     = seconds % 60;

           text3.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

           h2.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shuffle2);

        text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);



        h2.postDelayed(run, 0);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);


        // Add the adView to it
        cShuffleView2 myView;
        myView=new cShuffleView2(this);
            layout.addView(myView);

    }

}
```

custom view class that does the animation

```
package besttecksolutions.tellafortune;



import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class cShuffleView2 extends View {

 View t;
 Bitmap icon;

 cShuffleView2( Context context)
    {
        super(context);


        // load in bitmaps
        try {
        AssetManager assetManager= context.getAssets();
       InputStream inputStream;
       inputStream=assetManager.open("bio.png");  
       icon=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
       inputStream.close();
        } catch( IOException e)
        {

        }

    }

 protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas)
    {
    Paint color = new Paint();
    color.setColor(0xffffff00);
    canvas.drawRect(0,0, getWidth(),getHeight(),color);
    canvas.drawBitmap(icon, 100,100,null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a public boolean field, or private with get/set, and set it to true in your timer callback (e.g. myView.updateBitmap = true;).   In onDraw, you can then test it:

```
if (this.updateBitmap){

    // update bitmap
    this.updateBitmap = false;

}
```

updateBitmap can only be true if it was set in your timer callback (assuming you don't use it anywhere else).

Even better would be to implement your own callback on your extended View then call that directly from the timer.

Comment: Hio,Thank you for your reply, what I wanted to do was move the bitmap each time the timer goes off.  In my timer code, would I have to call invaliudate to force a redraw, then in the 0nDraw have the flag code?

Comment: Yes.  invalidate anywhere you want.  Because updateBitmap is set only in the timer, your bitmnap is redrawn only when the timer callback fires.